# Percorrer Objetos de Objetos

Tags: javascript, json, objetos

Como percorrer Objetos em JS?

Tipo, tenho um Json

```
{
  children":[
    {}
  ]
}
```

a questao é, que as vezes existem objetos dentro de objetos e as vezes nao, dentro desse children, posso ter outro children, e assim em diante.

Comment: Podes explicar o que pretendes fazer? `children` é uma array, queres aceder uma a uma, mudar algo, substituir, ?? Dá uma exemplo para a pergunta ficar mais clara.

Comment: quero montar uma arvore,

Comment: Exemplo:

Pasta
   Subpasta
   Subpasta
      Subpasta da Subpasta

Pasta 2
  Subpasta


entendeu?

Comment: Não entendi. Tenta explicar melhor com um caso prático. O assunto não é complexo mas dificil saber o que estás à procura só assim.

Comment: Tipo um treegrid, eu quero basicamente exibir um treegrid, conforme meu json retorna, porem quando é pra retornar só um, tudo bem, mas nao sei como retornar, isso para fazer um treegrid

Comment: O que queres mostrar num formato JSON? Uma estrutura de diretorias? dados de uma empresa? Ou queres mostrar/aceder a um JSON que já tens? nesse caso da um exemplo da estrutura e diz o que precisas extrair dele.

Comment: Eu ja tenho um JSON, e quero montar uma estrutura de pastas e subpastas (e subpastas de subpastas), conforme o JSON retorna. Tipo uma "arvore"

Comment: Rafael, podes dar um exemplo do JSON que tens? Essas pastas vão estar onde? no servidor/Node.js ou queres montar HTML com a estrutura do teu JSON. Explica mais a tua duvida... senão não podemos ajudar, apesar de sabermos de certeza a resposta para o teu problema.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/suqiwesato/edit?html,js,output

Comment: No link a cima tem um exemplo do meu JSON.
Eu quero listar em tela eles. os childens, sao subpastas
Ficaria mais ou menos assim

- Pasta Principal
    - Subpasta
         - Subpasta da subpastas
               - Subpasta da subpata da subpasta
    - Subpasta

- Outra pasta principal

Comment: Otimo, já temos algo concreto. E o que queres fazer com o JSON? criar HTML? usar com uma API? ou como vais usar o JSON?

Comment: Quero renderizar na tela, mostrar no HTML

Comment: Ok! Estamos perto. Que parte do JSON queres mostrar? podes dar um exemplo de como o HTML deve ser com os dados (ainda que não saibas como os colocar lá).

Comment: Eu so quero exibir o nome, conseguindo exibir em arquiterura eu monto um HTML, pode ser em lista ou de qualquer outra forma.

quero exibir o nome da pasta que esta no NAME do json, e o nome das subpastas que esta nos childens tambem no NAME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```
function criarSubPasta(obj, parent) {
  // criar <li>nome</li>
  var nameLi = document.createElement('li'); 
  nameLi.innerHTML = obj.name;
  parent.appendChild(nameLi);

  // parar aqui se não houver children
  if (!obj.children) return;

  // preparar um novo <ul></ul> para as subpastas
  var childrenLi = document.createElement('li');
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  parent.appendChild(childrenLi);
  childrenLi.appendChild(ul);
  obj.children.forEach(function(child) {
    // correr a mesma lógica recursivamente nas subpastas
    criarSubPasta(child, ul);
  });
}

criarSubPasta(json, document.querySelector('ul'));
```

#### Exemplo:

```js
var json = [{
  "id": "152",
  "repository": "1",
  "name": "Repositório",
  "created_by": {
    "id": "14",
    "name": "",
    "username": ""
  },
  "created_at": "",
  "last_updated_by": {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "",
    "username": ""
  },
  "last_updated_at": "",
  "children": [{
      "id": "688",
      "repository": "1",
      "parent": "152",
      "name": "Licitações",
      "created_by": "6",
      "created_at": "2147483647",
      "last_updated_by": "245",
      "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
      "active": "1",
      "children": [{
          "id": "722",
          "repository": "1",
          "parent": "688",
          "name": "Federais",
          "created_by": "6",
          "created_at": "2147483647",
          "last_updated_by": "7",
          "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
          "active": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "724",
          "repository": "1",
          "parent": "688",
          "name": "Estaduais",
          "created_by": "6",
          "created_at": "2147483647",
          "last_updated_by": "7",
          "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
          "active": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "740",
          "repository": "1",
          "parent": "688",
          "name": "Municipais",
          "created_by": "245",
          "created_at": "2147483647",
          "last_updated_by": "7",
          "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
          "active": "1",
          "children": [{
            "id": "778",
            "repository": "1",
            "parent": "740",
            "name": "2017",
            "created_by": "7",
            "created_at": "1484311566",
            "last_updated_by": "7",
            "last_updated_at": "1484311566",
            "active": "1"
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "689",
      "repository": "1",
      "parent": "152",
      "name": "Dossiê Funcional",
      "created_by": "6",
      "created_at": "2147483647",
      "last_updated_by": "6",
      "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
      "active": "1",
      "children": [{
          "id": "704",
          "repository": "1",
          "parent": "689",
          "name": "Matriz",
          "created_by": "6",
          "created_at": "2147483647",
          "last_updated_by": "7",
          "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
          "active": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "718",
          "repository": "1",
          "parent": "689",
          "name": "Filiais",
          "created_by": "236",
          "created_at": "2147483647",
          "last_updated_by": "7",
          "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
          "active": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "690",
      "repository": "1",
      "parent": "152",
      "name": "Notas Fiscais",
      "created_by": "6",
      "created_at": "2147483647",
      "last_updated_by": "6",
      "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
      "active": "1",
      "children": [{
          "id": "697",
          "repository": "1",
          "parent": "690",
          "name": "Serviço",
          "created_by": "6",
          "created_at": "2147483647",
          "last_updated_by": "6",
          "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
          "active": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "698",
          "repository": "1",
          "parent": "690",
          "name": "Material",
          "created_by": "6",
          "created_at": "2147483647",
          "last_updated_by": "6",
          "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
          "active": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "699",
          "repository": "1",
          "parent": "690",
          "name": "Despesas",
          "created_by": "6",
          "created_at": "2147483647",
          "last_updated_by": "6",
          "last_updated_at": "2147483647",
          "active": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

function criarSubPasta(obj, parent) {
  var nameLi = document.createElement('li');
  nameLi.innerHTML = obj.name;
  parent.appendChild(nameLi);
  if (!obj.children) return;
  var childrenLi = document.createElement('li');
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  parent.appendChild(childrenLi);
  childrenLi.appendChild(ul);
  obj.children.forEach(function(child) {
    criarSubPasta(child, ul);
  });
}
json.forEach(function(obj) {
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
  criarSubPasta(obj, ul);
});
```

Comment: se caso meu json retornar mais pastas dentro de pasta, funciona tambem?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto sim, desde que cada objeto tenha uma propriedade `children` que seja array. Não importa a profundidade.

Comment: ele tem sim, me desculpe, mas meu json retorna [] no inicio, ai da erro, se eu tiro funciona, como fazer?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto podes explicar melhor _"meu json retorna [] no inicio"_? Queres dizer que recebes o json 2 vezes? uma vazio e a outra completo?

Comment: nao, ele vem assim o inicio

[  
   {  
      "id":"152",
      "repository":"1",
      "name":"Reposit\u00f3rio",
      "created_by":{  
         "id":"14",
         "name":"",
         "username":""
      }.....

Comment: @RafaelAugusto ah, ok. E tem só uma entrada? ou várias?

Comment: so essa no inicio e uma fechando no final

Comment: e claro, varios resultados dentro, mas os resultados sao como te mandei a cima

Comment: @RafaelAugusto pena não teres dado o JSON correto no inicio. Mas corrigi agora, precisa só de um `forEach` basicamente.

Comment: Desculpa, eu achei que isso nao faria diferencia

Comment: @RafaelAugusto não tem problema. Ficas a saber mais sobre como o site funciona :) Se a resposta resolveu o teu problema podes clicar para marcar como aceite.

Comment: eu nao consegui implementar, onde eu usaria o forEach?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto vê na resposta, eu atualizei o exemplo, no final da parte executavel. Encontras?

Comment: Ata, desculpa, funcionou, Obrigado :D